# Override issue: does exist a method in Object to override?

Tags: java, overriding

I have a class A, that I can't modify. B extend A, I can modify B and it has the method getStuff().
C1 extend A (I can't modify C1), and C2 extend C1. I can modify C2 and it has the method getStuff().
The problem is that A doesn't have the method getStuff() so I can't override getStuff() and I've to put cast and "if". (I know only this solution).

Does it exist a method in the Object class, that return a INT, that I can override in B and C2? (I can rename getStuff()).
Or does it exist some programming trick (or best practices) to do this?

I defined the class in this way:

```
A myA;
if (...) myA = new B; else myA = new C2;
```

I would like to call myA.getStuff()

Comment: Why do you have to overwrite a method?

Comment: Why can't you just create a class that extends either B or C2?

Comment: why A does not have getStuff()!!!

Comment: I edited and added a comment on @laune reply. The downvote are faster than the clarification question... LOL :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Stuff {
    int getStuff();
}

class B extends A implements Stuff { ... }

class C2 extends C1 implements Stuff { ... }
```

This should achieve what I think you want?!

You may use a reference of the "common type" `Stuff` to accomodate references to B or C2:

```
Stuff myA;
if (...) myA = new B(); else myA = new C2();

myA.getStuff();
```

Or you can use A, but you'll have to cast in order to call getStuff:

```
A myA;
if (...) myA = new B(); else myA = new C2();

((Stuff)myA).getStuff();
```

Comment: The problem of override was that I've to put an "if" cast to B or to C2. With interface I can cast to the interface without if, right?               ((Stuff) myA).getStuff();

Comment: See my addition to the A - how to use it, either way.

Comment: But in this way I can't access to the method of A and C1, I can access only to the interface method, right?